# Highcharts Ordinal Issue

Tags: json, datetime, highcharts, ordinal

I am struggling to understand why I cannot get the ordinal aspect of my spline type chart to work correctly! I created a series of bar charts a long time ago but having not done anything like this in years I'm a tad clueless and needing some guidance, I've spent hours trying different methods and nothing works wether using Highcharts or highstock.

The code I have in the head of my page is as follows:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                    text: theTitle,
                    x: -20              
            },
            xAxis: {
                ordinal: false,
                type:'datetime',
                labels: {formatter: function() {return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e (%y)', this.value);}}   
            },
            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("data_weight_loss.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
        
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

The dates are in datestamp format in my MySQL database as "2022-06-28 09:02:45" and despite trying all sorts I'm confused to how I can get the dates in my chart to add the dates in that don't already exist?

[image: HighChart showing weight loss measured at random intervals]

This image shows the chart on how it currently looks but has no relevance as the dates that are missing means the chart is not very helpful. It's been a long time since I used Highcharts and even did anything like this but as a personal project I'd love to get my chart working with the ordinal aspect in place. Is there anything glaringly obvious that I have done wrong?

The data for instance is like this if I look directly in the data call from the php page.

> [{"name":"Date","data":[1651695362000,1652140800000,1652227200000,1652313600000,1652400000000,1652918400000,1653264000000,1654214400000,1654473600000,1654560000000,1654819200000,1655164800000,1655251200000,1655424000000,1655683200000,1656288000000]},{"name":"Weight","data":[2188,2000,1986,1962,1948,1868,1834,1744,1728,1720,1702,1682,1676,1666,1652,1622]}]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Palendrone, First of all, the `ordinal` feature occurs only in Highstock, but I am not sure if this is the option that you are looking for. Do you want to show gaps between data, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xspmrnjz/

Comment: @ppotaczek yes exactly that!

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek, that helped me nail the answer. Your expertise and help has been brilliant :0)